# What does a circled plus mean?

Tags: math, cryptography, matrix

I cannot understand the calculation "66 ⊕ fa = 9c". 
The sum is clearly over "ff", so I am confused. 
The topic is simple encryption algorithm.

**What does a circled plus mean?**

Comment: The unicode character itself is called: "Circled plus" with code point: U+2295 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2295/index.htm

Answer (score 81, accepted):

People are saying that the symbol doesn't mean addition. This is true, but doesn't explain why a plus-like symbol is used for something that isn't addition.

The answer is that for modulo addition of 1-bit values, 0+0 == 1+1 == 0, and 0+1 == 1+0 == 1. Those are the same values as XOR.

So, plus in a circle in this context means "bitwise addition modulo-2". Which is, as everyone says, XOR for integers. It's common in mathematics to use plus in a circle for an operation which is a sort of addition, but isn't regular integer addition.

Comment: Thank you for your mathematical explanation. I was initially confused as I had seen the sign here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition But it is clearly different operation.

Comment: If you consider a byte to be a matrix with 8 columns and 1 row (or the other way around), taken over the finite field of order 2, then actually it is matrix addition :-)

Comment: Don't forget that there is also a lot of reuse of notations in mathematics. Sometimes you really need to know the context to know the meaning of a particular symbol.

Answer (score 20):

This is not an plus, but the sign for the binary operator [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR)

```
a   b   a XOR b
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

Comment: Generally speaking, the circled plus denotes a binary operation that is treated like addition. In finite filed arithmetics, it's addition modulo characteristic of the field. In computer applications, the characteristic is usually 2. Then ⊕ is equal to XOR since `(a + b) mod 2` is equal `(a XOR b)` if a and b are 0 or 1. However, it's not true for finite fields with characteristic 3 and above. Addition modulo 3 is not XOR.

Answer (score 9):

It's not an addition, but an exclusive OR operation. At least the output confirms to the same.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That's the XOR operator, not the PLUS operator

XOR works bit by bit, without carrying over like PLUS does

```
1 XOR 1 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope this layout works, take it to the binary representation with an [**XOR**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or):

```
66h = 102 decimal = 01100110 binary
FAh = 250 decimal = 11111010 binary
------------------------------------
                    10011100 binary <------ that's 9Ch/156 decimal
```

  XOR rules are basically:
- 1 XOR 1 = 0 false

  1 XOR 0 = 1 true

  0 XOR 0 = 0 false

but the wiki I linked earlier will give you more details if needed...thats what it looks like they are doing in the screenshot you provided

Comment: lol, guess my "a new answer was posted" wasn't working this morning...I got a bar up top that said "undefined", nothing is funnier than writing up a response, submitting, and then seeing a dozen new ones :)

Answer (score 5):

The plus-symbol in a circle does not denote addition. It is a XOR operation.

Answer (score 4):

It's an exclusive or (XOR). If I remember correctly, when doing bitwise mathematics the dot (.) means AND and the plus (+) means OR. Putting a circle around the plus to mean XOR is consistent with the style used for OR.

Answer (score 1):

I used the logic in the replies by rampion and schnaader. I will summarise how I confirmed the results. I changed the numbers to binary and then used the XOR-operation. Alternatively, you can use the Hexadecimal tables: [Click here!](http://www.garykessler.net/library/byte_logic_table.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is XOR. Another name for the XOR function is addition without carry. I suppose that's how the symbol might make sense.

Comment: Hi. You won't get any Upvotes in Stackoverflow by suppliyng answers that have already been given. You might even get downvotes for that in future

Comment: The risk with a downvote in such a scenario is that it might imply that an answer is incorrect rather than an unnecessary duplication.